# Data is inserting if its manually inserted, but not working in forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backend

### Its not working in this code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Sample() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    personalInfo: {
      surName: '',
      givenName: '',
      middleName: '',
      extension: '',
      civilStatus: '',
      sex: '',
      age: '',
      dateOfBirth: '',
      placeOfBirth: '',
      religion: '',
      mobileNumber: '',
      idCardNumber: '',
      idCardType: '',
      landlineNumber: '',
      presentAddress: '',
      educationalAttainment: '',
      profession: '',
      occupation: '',
      monthlyIncome: '',
      nameOfEmployer: '',
      employerAddress: '',
      contactNumber: '',
    },
    familyComposition: [
      {
        name: '',
        age: '',
        sex: '',
        relationShip: '',
        educationalAttainment: '',
        occupation: '',
        monthlyIncome: '',
      },
    ],
  });

  // Update the form state for personal information
  const handlePersonalInfoChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // Update the form state for family members
  const handleFamilyMemberChange = (index, e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormState((prevState) => {
      const updatedFamilyComposition = [...prevState.familyComposition];
      updatedFamilyComposition[index] = {
        ...updatedFamilyComposition[index],
        [name]: value,
      };
      return { ...prevState, familyComposition: updatedFamilyComposition };
    });
  };

  // Add a new family member to the form state
  const handleAddFamilyMember = () => {
    setFormState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      familyComposition: [
        ...prevState.familyComposition,
        {
          name: '',
          age: '',
          sex: '',
          relationShip: '',
          educationalAttainment: '',
          occupation: '',
          monthlyIncome: '',
        },
      ],
    }));
  };

  // Remove a family member from the form state
  const handleRemoveFamilyMember = (index) => {
    setFormState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      familyComposition: prevState.familyComposition.filter((_, i) => i !== index),
    }));
  };

  // Handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      // Log the form data before submitting
      console.log('Form Data:', formState);

      // Send POST request to the backend endpoint
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/create-solo-parent-account', formState);
      alert(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
      alert('Error submitting form. Check the console for details.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* Personal Information Section */}
      <h2>Personal Information</h2>
      <label>Surname: <input type="text" name="surName" value={formState.surName} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Given Name: <input type="text" name="givenName" value={formState.givenName} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Middle Name: <input type="text" name="middleName" value={formState.middleName} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Extension: <input type="text" name="extension" value={formState.extension} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Civil Status: <input type="text" name="civilStatus" value={formState.civilStatus} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Sex: <input type="text" name="sex" value={formState.sex} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Age: <input type="number" name="age" value={formState.age} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" value={formState.dateOfBirth} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Place of Birth: <input type="text" name="placeOfBirth" value={formState.placeOfBirth} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Religion: <input type="text" name="religion" value={formState.religion} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Mobile Number: <input type="tel" name="mobileNumber" value={formState.mobileNumber} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>ID Card Number: <input type="text" name="idCardNumber" value={formState.idCardNumber} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>ID Card Type: <input type="text" name="idCardType" value={formState.idCardType} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Landline Number: <input type="tel" name="landlineNumber" value={formState.landlineNumber} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Present Address: <input type="text" name="presentAddress" value={formState.presentAddress} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Educational Attainment: <input type="text" name="educationalAttainment" value={formState.educationalAttainment} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Profession: <input type="text" name="profession" value={formState.profession} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Occupation: <input type="text" name="occupation" value={formState.occupation} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Monthly Income: <input type="text" name="monthlyIncome" value={formState.monthlyIncome} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Name of Employer: <input type="text" name="nameOfEmployer" value={formState.nameOfEmployer} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Employer Address: <input type="text" name="employerAddress" value={formState.employerAddress} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      <label>Contact Number: <input type="tel" name="contactNumber" value={formState.contactNumber} onChange={handlePersonalInfoChange} /></label>

      {/* Family Composition Section */}
      <h2>Family Composition</h2>
      {formState.familyComposition.map((familyMember, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <label>
            Family Member Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`name`}
              value={familyMember.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Age:
            <input
              type="number"
              name={`age`}
              value={familyMember.age}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Sex:
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`sex`}
              value={familyMember.sex}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Relationship:
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`relationShip`}
              value={familyMember.relationShip}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Educational Attainment:
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`educationalAttainment`}
              value={familyMember.educationalAttainment}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Occupation:
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`occupation`}
              value={familyMember.occupation}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Monthly Income:
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`monthlyIncome`}
              value={familyMember.monthlyIncome}
              onChange={(e) => handleFamilyMemberChange(index, e)}
            />
          </label>

          <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveFamilyMember(index)}>
            Remove Family Member
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddFamilyMember}>
        Add Family Member
      </button>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Sample;
```

### But working with this code

```
import axios from 'axios';

function Sample(){

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
      personalInfo: {
        surName: "Razon",
        givenName: "Mark Nicholas",
        middleName: "L.",
        extension: "Jr",
        civilStatus: "Single",
        sex: "Male",
        age: 25,
        dateOfBirth: "1998-01-01",
        placeOfBirth: "Cityville",
        religion: "Christian",
        mobileNumber: "123-456-7890",
        idCardNumber: "ABC123",
        idCardType: "Driver's License",
        landlineNumber: "987-654-3210",
        presentAddress: "123 Main St, Cityville",
        educationalAttainment: "Bachelor's Degree",
        profession: "Software Developer",
        occupation: "Web Developer",
        monthlyIncome: 5000,
        nameOfEmployer: "Tech Company",
        employerAddress: "456 Tech St, Tech City",
        contactNumber: "555-1234",
      },
      familyComposition: [
        {
          name: "Jane Doe",
          age: 30,
          sex: "Female",
          relationShip: "Spouse",
          educationalAttainment: "Master's Degree",
          occupation: "Doctor",
          monthlyIncome: 7000,
        },
        {
          name: "Alice Doe",
          age: 10,
          sex: "Female",
          relationShip: "Child",
          educationalAttainment: "Elementary",
          occupation: "Student",
          monthlyIncome: 0,
        },
      ],
    };

    try {
      // Send POST request to the backend endpoint
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/create-solo-parent-account', formData);

      // Handle the response as needed
      alert(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
      if (error.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        console.error('Response status:', error.response.status);
        console.error('Response headers:', error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        console.error('No response received. Request details:', error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        console.error('Error details:', error.message);
      }
      alert('Error submitting form. Check the console for details.');
    }
  };

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Sample;
```

#### Npm install packages

```
npm install axios cors dotenv express express-pino-logger jsforce multer pg pino nodemon
```

## Issue with Nested State Updates in React Form

#### Problem Description:

I am currently facing an issue with updating state in a React form that collects both personal information and family composition. The form uses the useState hook, and the state is structured with nested objects for personal information (personalInfo) and an array for family composition (familyComposition).

#### Problem Details:

In the personal information section, I am using the handlePersonalInfoChange function to update the state. However, it seems that the state is not updating correctly, and when I log the form data before submission, the personal information fields are empty.

In the family composition section, I am using the handleFamilyMemberChange function to update the state for each family member. While this works for adding and removing members, there might be an issue with how I am updating the nested array.

#### Code Samples:

I have provided two sets of code snippets. The first set represents the full React component, which is not working as expected. The second set, a simplified version of the form, is working when I submit the data directly without user input.

#### Things I've Tried:

I have already checked for typos and ensured that the name attributes in the input fields match the structure of the state. I suspect that the issue might be related to how I am updating the state within nested structures.

#### Expected Behavior:

I expect that when I input data into the form, the state should be updated correctly, and when I log the form data before submission, all fields should have the entered values.

#### Additional Information:

- I have included the npm packages installed in my project.
- The backend server is set up and running without issues.
- I am using axios for making POST requests to the backend endpoint.

Any assistance in identifying and resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This function is setting `formState[name]`, but needs to set `formState.personalInfo[name]`:

```
const handlePersonalInfoChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setFormState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name]: value,
  }));
};
```

So it should probably look like:

```
const handlePersonalInfoChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setFormState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    personalInfo: {
        ...prevState.personalInfo,
        [name]: value,
    }
  }));
};
```

Comment: Still the console says

POST http://localhost:3001/api/create-solo-parent-account 500 (Internal Server Error)

Error submitting form:

Comment: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Answer (score 0):

// Update the form state for personal information by using reference to personalInfo

```
const handlePersonalInfoChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setFormState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    personalInfo: {
      ...prevState.personalInfo,
      [name]: value,
    },
  }));
};
```